# rename image filename to foldername in sequence

Tags: linux, image, rename

I have around 5000 images that I'd like to rename based on it's folder name

Example

```
Vacation Picture
---2013
------Vegas-Trip
---------DCS001.jpg
---------DSC002.jpg
---------etc
------China-Trip
---------DSC0100.jpg
---------DSC0101.jpg
```

What I want to do is have the  all the .jpg files all rename to example Vegas-Trip-001.jpg Vegas-Trip-002.jpg etc. Then once it goes into the China-Trip folder it will rename it China-Trip-001.jpg and continue on for each folder.

I've done some searching but I can't seem to find anything.

Running Linux.

TIA

Comment: You need to write a shell script to do this.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started

```sh
cd 'Vacation Picture/2013'
for picdir in *
do
  cd $picdir
  for pic in *
  do
    mv $pic $(sed "s/DSC/${picdir}-/" <<< $pic)
  done
  cd ..
done
```